# Netplan/Network backend in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server

Hope everyone is doing good.

My server is configured with static IP using netplan. I'm confused about the ubuntu 20.04LTS server network backends.

- According to the Netplan Documentation netplan default beckend is systemd-networkd and default renderer is networkd unless changed to NetworkManager.
- Network should stop working if I stop network service.
- To day I have turned off all network related services for testing purpose one by one(network.target systemd-networkd.service systemd-networkd.socket networkd-dispatcher.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service network-online.target network-pre.target)
  but still I can ping and ssh the machine.

Can any one help me to understand this behaviour of networking and what backend service is controlling the networking.

Thanks